# Query to display unique comments based on certain conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

TABLE DEFINITION

```
ColumnName  Comments
CustomerID  INT
SequenceNo  INT
Comments    VARCHAR(MAX)
```

CUSTOMER TABLE

```
CustomerID  SequenceNo  Comments
1   1   ABC D
1   2   CDE
1   3   ABC
1   4   ABC D
1   5   CDE
1   6   abc
2   7   ABC DEF
2   8   
2   9   ABC DEF
2   10  DEF
2   11  XYZ 123
2   12  ABC
3   13  PQ RST
```

OUTPUT

```
CustomerID  SequenceNo  Comments
1   3   ABC
1   4   ABC D
1   5   CDE
1   6   abc
2   8   
2   9   ABC DEF
2   10  DEF
2   11  XYZ 123
2   12  ABC
3   13  PQ RST
```

Records should be filtered by 
1.  Display only Unique Comments from Customer Table for all the customers,
2.  If Comments are same then display the row which has maximum SequenceNo

Comment: Can you post the query you have so far?

Comment: Google and learn about ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY...)

Answer (score 1):

This assumes you are using a case sensitive collation

```
SELECT CustomerID,
       MAX(SequenceNo) AS SequenceNo,
       Comments
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY CustomerID,Comments
ORDER BY CustomerID,MAX(SequenceNo)
```

If you are not using a case sensitive collation, then try this:

```
SELECT CustomerID,
       MAX(SequenceNo) AS SequenceNo,
       Comments COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY CustomerID,Comments COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS
ORDER BY CustomerID,MAX(SequenceNo)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions for this:

```
select c.*
from (select c.*,
             row_number() over (partition by CustomerId, Comments
                                order by SequenceNo desc) as seqnum
      from comments c
     ) c
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: He only needs distinct combinations of CustomerID and Comments with the max sequenceNo. I don't think there's any need for row_number()

Comment: But why change a simple group by into a derived table with a windows function? It is just unnecessary complexity.

Comment: @Stephan . . . In case the OP actually wants other columns as well.